# Extract string from tuple embedded in a list, Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, tuples, dataformat

Apologies in advance if this question has already been asked, have done some searching but no luck.

TL;DR: Trying to pull second piece of a tuple out as a string.

I am building a script with python3 that pulls information from LDAP and returns what is hopefully actionable data.

```
def GetMembersWDept():
    i2 = input('Please input the department number. Examples: 2410, 2417\n')
    criteria = '(&(objectClass=User)(department=' + i2 + '*))'
    print ('Search criteria set to: \t\t' + criteria)
    searchDC = 'dc=example,dc=com'
    print ('Searching location: \t\t\t' + searchDC)
    print ()
    out = []
    result = c.search(searchDC, criteria, \
        SEARCH_SCOPE_WHOLE_SUBTREE, attributes = ['department'])  \
        # request a few object from the ldap server
    if result:
        for r in c.response:
            if (r['type'] == 'searchResEntry'):
                out.append(r['dn'])
                out.append(r['attributes']) # comes out in tuple form
            else:
                pass
    else:
        print('result', conn.result)
    return out
```

This works well for pulling out the CN of the members in that department but not for extracting whatever additional information, in this case the department, is appended.

A sample output is:

Search criteria set to:         (&(objectClass=User)(department=2417*))
Searching location:             dc=ple,dc=com

> ['CN=First Last,OU=ex,OU=am,DC=ple,DC=com', {'department': ['1234']},
>   'CN=Another Person,OU=ex,OU=am,DC=ple,DC=com', {'department':
>   ['1234']}]

How can I pull out the second portion of the tuple, i.e. '1234', as a string instead? The endgame here would be to format the data as:

> [First Last, 1234, Another Person, 1234]

... so I can use it in another function that compares the department and returns the name if conditions are not met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If output is:

```
['CN=First Last,OU=ex,OU=am,DC=ple,DC=com', {'department': ['1234']}, 'CN=Another Person,OU=ex,OU=am,DC=ple,DC=com', {'department': ['1234']}]
```

then you can set that equal to `newresult` and do:

```
print(list(newresult[1].values())[0][0])
```

This assumes that the element in the list with the department is always in position 1, that the dictionary always has 1 value to it, and that the department number you want is the only item in the list.

Comment: This works and returns 1234 as above. If the individuals were from different departments (say 1234, 2345), is there a way to apply this same method to pull both or any number of departments? I had been hoping to display DN, dept, DN, dept, etc without omitting repeats ... Also, thank you for the quick and accurate response! :)

Comment: Yes, you'd exclude the last `[0]` so it would read `print(list(newresult[1].values())[0])` , which gives you the list of departments

Comment: Read your question wrong, it would just be `print(list(newresult[3].values())[0][0])`

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it would be simpler to use `c.search_s` instead of `c.search`, unless you have good reasons to do so (or you should show how you are creating your response).

From python-ldap documentation : 
`search_s` directly returns a list of 2-tuple *(dn, attrs), where dn is a string containing the DN (distinguished name) of the entry, and attrs is a dictionary containing the attributes associated with the entry. The keys of attrs are strings, and the associated values are lists of strings*

So for each tuple `entry` you have :

```
dn = entry[0]
departement = entry[1]{'department'}[0]
```

Comment: I'm not saying that the suggested would not be more preferable but for anyone referencing this answer, I have not been able to make it work yet. It returns:File "ADQueryViaScript.py", line 175, in GetMembersWDept
    result = c.search_s(searchDC, criteria, \
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'search_s'

Comment: Additionally, this is python3-ldap which isn't exactly a one-for-one match with the more developed and better documented python-ldap from what I've been able to determine.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.